# findViewByTag within a dialog

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialog

I've got a custom dialog layout that has two EditText fields and I've initially set the visibility to GONE for both (in the layout XML). In the dialog onCreate I want to do a findViewByTag to locate one of the two EditText fields so I can switch visibility to VISIBLE. Everything works find in the dialog if I switch visibility in the XML but I don't know how to get a reference to the dialog's main View from within the dialog so I can call findViewByTag.

I am inflating the layout in the dialog class's onCreate because that's how the example I found did it. I'm willing to change that if necessary to get the reference in the caller and set visibility before showing the dialog if that's the best way to do it.

Still pretty new to Android so any tips on how best to handle custom dialogs is appreciated.

Comment: findViewByTag wil only work as expected if your Objects you put as Tag have a "well written" equals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this example from outside of a view class.

```
Dialog amazingDialog = new Dialog(context);

amazingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.amazingdialogcontentview)
MyAmazingView view = (MyAmazingView)amazingDialog.findViewById(R.id.amazingview);
TextView tv = (TextView)amazingDialog.findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what your use case is, so there may be a better way to do this if you have access to some member variables you could initialize in onCreate, but if you don't:

You could try

```
View parent = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.parentId)
```

to get a known parent view of those EditTexts, and then call

```
parent.findViewWithTag(myTag)
```

to find your EditText.

Looking at the way you've phrased your question, and the fact you said you're new at Android, are you familiar with the difference between IDs and Tags?

An ID is a resource number assigned to an item (e.g., a View) by Android when you tell it to give something a name.  You'd declare, in your XML:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView"/> <!--with other parameters as necessary-->
```

And then you'd use

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

to find that TextView.

A Tag is an object that you can attach to a View (which I am pretty sure you can't do by XML), either for finding it later or for persisting some interesting information about it to use whenever you might next look it up (like a data object associated with its contents).  So, you might say:

```
tv.setTag(myInterestingData);
```

so that you could later look up myInterestingData just by having a reference to tv.

Comment: You can set the tags in XML with android:tag which is what I was attempting to use. My goal was to find the edit fields witout actually knowing the ID ahead of time.  Tag allows for that if they are well formed.

Answer (score 0):

After much reading and trial and error, I've concluded that the only way to do this is to use multiple EditText in the XML, all with visibility="gone". Then, in the Java code, have an if or switch to lookup and show the control either by tag or by ID. I was just trying to force too much abstraction into the Dialog class. With the multiple EditText I can use the class for multiple dialogs instead of having one class for each dialog.